# ValueError: Not enough values to unpack when using pickle

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, nlp, load, pickle

I tried to look at others questions but could not fin my answer. I do not understand why I have this error :

```
 File "lexicon_based.py", line 50, in <module>
    for word, (pos, neu, neg) in zip(pickle.load(fd)):
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

The part of the code where the error seems to come :

```
with open("dict_pickle", "rb") as fd:
    dico_lexique = {}
    for word, (pos, neu, neg) in zip(pickle.load(fd)):
        dico_lexique[word] = Sentiment(int(pos), int(neu), int(neg))
```

Code to create the object " dict_pickle", the initial file has at least 400000 lines :

```
with codecs.open('lexiconSentiment.txt', 'r', 'Cp1252', errors = 'ignore') as text_file:
    text_file =(text_file.read())
    #print(text_file)

dico_lexique =  ({i.split(";")[1]:i.split(";")[2:] for i in text_file.split("\n") if i}) # Spliting the text content and creating a dictionary
#print(dico_lexique)
#print(type(dico_lexique))

pickle_out = open("dict_pickle", "wb")
pickle.dump(dico_lexique, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()
```

how the dictionary file looks before using pickle :

```
0;***;21;127;0
1;vraiment;407;156;37
2;oiseau-à-berceau;102;259;0
3;Stoph;95;308;37
4;Conscience;372;144;35
5;rançonnement;0;635;433
6;provenir;304;227;47
7;féliciteur;285;54;1
8;traversée;360;167;38
9;avant toute chose;241;108;34
10;Porcellis;52;276;0
11;Lasker-Schüler;146;284;0
12;discréditer;0;47;866
13;adjuration;300;44;40
14;Besnier-Boeck-Schaumann;0;39;315
```

Comment: Any example lines from `lexiconSentiment.txt` ?

Comment: @alvas , hello it looks like this :  0;***;21;127;0
1;vraiment;407;156;37
2;oiseau-à-berceau;102;259;0
3;Stoph;95;308;37
4;Conscience;372;144;35
5;rançonnement;0;635;433
6;provenir;304;227;47
7;féliciteur;285;54;1
8;traversée;360;167;38
9;avant toute chose;241;108;34
10;Porcellis;52;276;0
11;Lasker-Schüler;146;284;0
12;discréditer;0;47;866
13;adjuration;300;44;40
14;Besnier-Boeck-Schaumann;0;39;315

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need `pickle.load(fd).items()` instead of `zip(pickle.load(fd))`. `zip()` is intended to work with iterables of iterables - not with dicts.

Comment: thank you but I now have this error :   File "lexicon_based.py", line 50, in <module>
    for word, (pos, neu, neg) in pickle.load(fd).items():
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)  I am really lost

Comment: You save ```i.split(";")[2:]```, and then you try to unpack this into ```pos, neu, neg```. Therefore, you implicitly assume that ```i.split(";")``` has exactly 5 elements (and pos, neu, neg are elements with indices 2,3,4, respectively). You should check this before saving your file.

Comment: And, by the way, you should use json or yaml instead of pickle in this case. These formats preserve the same information as pickle (dictionary of strings and ints), and they are human-readable, so you can check their consistence manually.